# I cant see the 'controls' for the rigacar addon

Tags: rigging

I couldn't see the controls for the riga car addonI found out that if I got into a separate file with a Mercedes car, I was able to toggle the visibility off and on with the value viewport display in the bone properties tab. But when I do the same with the original animation that I was aiming to make, (hence all the questions above about this questions about the widget), I cannot see the 'widgets' that control the car suspensions, drift handle, and ground sensors when I turn the hide option on and off, all i can see is a slight change in the textures of the bridge (which are farther away), I cannot see the controls. i can also see a small orange dot below the car when i click on DEF.body, DEF.wheel, it also moves with the car however i cannot see the 'controls' that are used to like control the suspension parameters, drift, ground sensors etc. Here's a photo   [image].

Comment: RigaCar is a third-party addon, not supplied as part of Blender which is what this Q&A site covers so you'll have to ask about it elsewhere. There does seem to be a [YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=488NFS4VTP0) about a bug in the addon, but I've no idea whether it covers the problem you're having with it.

Comment: ok thanks, i' will go watch the YT tutorial